# Problems with waiting for Word to start

Tags: notepad++, autohotkey, onenote

I'm writing a little script (my first in AutoHotKey) to copy Notepad++-code with Syntax-Highlighting to OneNote. It works by first pressing the "Copy HTML to clipboard" entry, pasting this into a new MSWord-document and cut it from there again, so the result is now in the clipboard.

Directly copying the HTML to OneNote doesn't work, because linebreaks are ignored there (Problem of  Microsoft and not notepad++. Look here: http://tech.lanesnotes.com/2012/05/pasting-code-to-onenote-with-formatting.html). But if you copy it to Word and than to OneNote, suddenly it works...

My problem: The code I wrote so far works, but only if Word was running before. If it has to startup first, the script fails and only prints an 'n' in a new Word-document. I'm very thankful to anyone who can help me there.

Edit 2:
I Forgot to mention: I use the german version of Notepad++ and Word, so the pressed keys may not be the right ones for you... -> changed the first send to !p (english).

```
;This script is used to copy notepad++-Syntax-Higlighting
;to clipboard in a format OneNote can read.
SetTitleMatchMode 2
#c::
IfWinActive, Notepad++
{
    send !p
    send n
    send {Right}
    send c
    send c
    send {Enter}


    Run winword.exe
    WinWaitActive, Microsoft Word
    WinActivate
    send ^v
    send ^a
    send ^x
    WinClose
    send n
}

SetTitleMatchMode 1
return
```

PS.: If you like this functionality, feel free to use this code. If you got a better idea or a proposal how to make it better, please tell me.

Comment: What happens if you "Copy RTF to Clipboard"? Can OneNote handle pasted Rich Text?

Comment: No, I tried, but you don't even get the paste-option. MSWord on the other hand does html and rtf perfectly...

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem. Running your script without `WinClose` and without `send n` (the last 2 lines of the block) will result in a clipboard containing the desired formatting that can directly be pasted in OneNote. That is, closing Word **before pasting** in OneNote will not work; oddly enough closing Word seems to restore the clipboard produced by NppExport. Find out exactly where the script fails on your machine (running word, activating, pasting, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use COM objects instead of sending keystrokes.

```
Wd := ComObjCreate("Word.Application") ;creates a new MS Word object
Wd.Documents.Add() ;adds a document
rng := Wd.ActiveDocument.Range(0,0) ;creates a range object at the
                                    ; start of the doc
rng.Paste() ;pastes the contents of the clipboard into the range object
rng.Copy() ;copies the range object into the clipboard
Wd.Quit(0) ;quits without saving changes
```

Comment: Sorry, the idea seems perfect, but all I get with this code are 2 errors with rng.Paste (Command failed) and rng.Copy (follow up error -> no text was selected).

Comment: Did you double check to make sure that there was text in the clipboard?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the little loading rectangle (is there a technical name for that?) counts as a "Microsoft Word" window, and it is active. My solution, that worked for me just now (no guarantees!), is to wait on a Word window with the default file name included, like so:

```
WinWaitActive Document1 - Microsoft Word
```

Does this work for you? If the German version defaults to something other than "Document1", put that there instead.

Now, where this is going to cause you problems is when you already have a Document1 open when you run this script.

**Edit:** This is also working for me:

```
WinWaitActive ahk_class MsoSplash
WinWaitActive Microsoft Word
```

This second solution may be even more problematic, since it will only work if you have no Word windows open before running winword.

**Edit number two:** How does the following work for you?

```
;This script is used to copy notepad++-Syntax-Higlighting
;to clipboard in a format OneNote can read.
SetTitleMatchMode 2
#c::
IfWinActive, Notepad++
{
    send !p
    send n
    send {Right}
    send c
    send c
    send {Enter}

    IfWinNotExist, ahk_class OpusApp
    {
        Run winword.exe
        WinWait, ahk_class MsoSplash
        WinWait, Microsoft Word
    }
    else
    {
        Run winword.exe
    }
    WinActivate, Microsoft Word
    send ^v
    send ^a
    send ^x
    ; WinClose
    Send !{F4}
    send n
}
SetTitleMatchMode 1
return
```

**Edit number three:** I replaced `WinClose` with `Send !{F4}`, which seems to work better.

**Edit number four:** I moved the WinActivate after the condition so that it applies to both cases, as recommended in a comment.

Comment: This works so far, but the window stays open. I tried "WinClose, ahk_class OpusApp" instead of WinClose, but then I get probems, if there are other windows open.

Comment: Try `Send !{F4}` instead. A lot of this is just trial-and-error with various searches of the AutoHotKey website.

Comment: This is almost perfect. But you have to add `sleep, 50` before `send ^v`, if I don't my notepad++ gets closed...

Comment: While tossing in a few `sleep` lines can definitely help when AHK goes too fast for applications, I don't get why Notepad++ closes for you. Does it just run through all of the commands in Notepad++, thus failing to use Word at all?

Comment: So, I looked into using a PID to identify the new window, since I'm thinking the problem lies with running Word once there is already an open window. Word doesn't seem to play nice with `Run, winword.exe, , , MyPID`.

Comment: Hmm, yesterday it would happen everytime without sleep. Now I can't reproduce it... The mysteries of code ;-)

Comment: Sorry, correction: It happens everythime, when I already have a open Word-window.

Comment: Everything works, if I transfer the WinActivate-line under the condition. Also: If you want to make the code more, beautiful transfer run winword.exe in front of "IfNotExists" and remove the else-block.

Comment: I don't know about running winword.exe before the `IfNotExists`, because the point of the condition is to determine whether Word is already running.

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ you can set it so that you can view all characters.

Click View --> Show Symbol -->  Show All Characters.

Then you can see exactly which characters are being used for the linebreak.

Then, copy and paste it to word and back into Notepad and compare the special characters that show up at the end of the line.

Then you can use Notepad++ or AutoHotkey to find and replace the end of line characters accordingly.

Comment: It's not about non-printing chars. It's about a problem, that OneNote2010 has with html-parsing. I know about notpad++'s features in this direction.